# jQuery Compare Issue

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code:

```
function loadPage(page, link) {
            if ($('div#content').attr('current') != page) {
                $('div#content').load(page, '', function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                    if (textStatus == 'error') {
                        $('div#content').html("<?php include 'error/404.php' ?>");  
                    };
                });
                var html = $('div#content').html();
                if (html != "<?php include 'error/404.php' ?>") {
                    $('div#content').hide().fadeIn('slow').attr('current', page);
                };
                $('div#header div#bottom div#nav ul#main li a').removeClass('active');
                $(link).addClass('active');
            };
        };
```

I don't understand why when it compares the html from the div (HTML from 'error/404.php' that has just been placed into div#content) with the source html (error/404.php), it isn't the same and doesn't follow the true path.

Any help guys?

Comment: Need a JSFiddle or something of the like to see the code in action. The strings look like they're the same, so we'd need to see in debug what's going on

Comment: `.load()` is asynchronous, so you are checking the content before it actually loads anything

Answer (score 2):

There must be some confusion here, the line:

```
$('div#content').html("<?php include 'error/404.php' ?>");
```

most likely not what you want to do. At this point you are at the browser, you don't have access to the backend like when you were back at the time when the response was generated. This only insert the literal html string into the `div#content` element, it has no way to run your `error/404.php` script from the javascript land.

What you probably wanted to do is make a new request back to the server that will run the `error/404.php` and return the output of that to the javascript call so you can insert it to the document. This general idea is called AJAX, and for your special case you can use jQuery's [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method to do it like this:

```
$('div#content').load('http://insert-full-url-here.com/error/4o4.php');
```

### Update:

The other issue is that asynchronism of `.load()` for your compares. Javascript is a single threaded environment, so when you request something to be `.load()` -ed it won't wait for that to be done, just runs trough and when the response does return kick off a callback. Your first load that looks like something like this:

```
$('div#content').load(page, '', ....
```

will not end and modify the dom tree when the condition right below it:

```
if (html != "<?php include 'error/404.php' ?>")
```

runs.

You will need to make that part of the code executed when the load did in fact returned. With `.load()` you can move the slideDown condition right into callback without the strange string compares:

```
$('div#content').load(page, '', function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
    if (textStatus != 'error') { // flipped the condition to NOT error
        $('div#content').hide().fadeIn('slow').attr('current', page); // do the part of the second test
    };
});
```

I'm not sure if the remaining two lines when should run, after or before the load takes place. if they need to be running when no error happens put it inside the div, if they need to run no matter of errors but after the load put them inside the `.load()`'s callback.

Newer jQuery returns commonjs promise based jqxhr objects from ajax related calls so the syntax could look like this:

```
$.get(page).done(function(resp){ // the .done() is called when there were no error
    $('div#content').html(resp);
    // anything you want to run on content get success
});
```

Comment: Sorry my fault for not saying - it doesn't run any PHP 'script' its just HTML on a PHP page that contains a <h2>Some text</h2>. For all thats its worth, it could be an HTML page. Sorry for not explaining!

Comment: I've updated the answer, i hope i now understand your intent right.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly just by looking at your code, but here's a path out of the woods:

```
    function loadPage(page, link) {
        if ($('div#content').attr('current') != page) {
            $('div#content').load(page, '', function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                if (textStatus == 'error') {
                    $('div#content').html("<?php include 'error/404.php' ?>");  
                };
            });
            var html = $('div#content').html();

            console.log(html); //Check the Value of html right before it is 
                               //compared. You might be surprised to see something 
                               //like 'undefined' or 'null' as the value. This 
                               //means html is comparing correctly, but is not 
                               //being instantiated properly.

            if (html != "<?php include 'error/404.php' ?>") {
                $('div#content').hide().fadeIn('slow').attr('current', page);
            };
            $('div#header div#bottom div#nav ul#main li a').removeClass('active');
            $(link).addClass('active');
        };
    };
```